# Javascript Observer function works on Chrome and IE but does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I've been working on javascipt functions to 'defer'  the execution of node X using observers. This works perfectly fine on Chrome and IE but does not function correctly in Firefox. Not sure if this is a compatibility issue or if I missed out a few lines of code.

// Observer Functions

```
function observer(callback) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if (!mutation.addedNodes) return;
            for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                var node = mutation.addedNodes[i]
                if($(node).hasClass('X')) {
                    callback();
                    observer.disconnect();
                }
            }
        });
    });
    observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true, attributes: false, characterData: false });
}


function observerFallback(callback) {
    var observerFallbackEvent = function(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName === 'OBJECT' && $(e.target).hasClass('X')) {
            callback();
            document.removeEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', observerFallbackEvent);
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', observerFallbackEvent);
}
```

Comment: Did you see any error in the console?

Comment: Describe better `does not function correctly in Firefox`???

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver shows that firefox 14.0 and above are supported. Check if the browser version is above that.

Comment: thanks guys the html file just needed an <!DOCTYPE html> i was using <!doctype html> lolxx